# How can I do to make the decorators work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have this code but it does not work :

```
def by2(c):
    return c*2

@by2
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

print(add(2,5))
```

I got when I try to execute it :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial about decorators?

Comment: And what did you expect this decorator to do?

Comment: Yes and I understood that when I type `add(2,5)` I should get `add(a,b) = by2(add(a,b))` so it should be 14.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators work differently. Decorators replace your function with another one. So decorator should return a new function. This:

```
@by2
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

is the same as this:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add = by2(add)
```

So what you need is:

```
def by2(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return func(*args) * 2 
    return wrapper

@by2
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(2, 5))
```